# Code is executed although condition is false

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a `view` V. 
Selecting data from this view takes about ten seconds to execute because of referencing to many many other views and tables. There's no way to change this.

Furthermore, there is a changelog table ( CL ) which holds information whether some datasets of V ( and / or some other tables / views have to be reloaded, e.g.:

```
id, refId, table
1, 1, V
2, 2, V
3, 3, A
4, 1, B
```

`id` is PK, auto-increment.
`refId` refers to the id-column of each referring table / view.
`table` holds the name of the referring table / view

Now, there is a query which checks if there are datasets in the CL referring to the view V.

Q1:

```
SELECT 
  V.*
FROM 
  CL
INNER JOIN V 
  ON V."id" = CL."refId"
  AND CL."table" = 'V'
```

In the above example, two records from CL are affected ( id 1 and 2 ).

If no record is affected at all ( no record with "table" = 'V' in CL ) I would expect an instant result of 0 executing the second query Q1 ( Thought the optimizer would determine that the join-condition returns 0 results in CL and therefore there is no need to execute the select on the view V which is the bottleneck, but it does. )

What I have tried after this:

a) Moving a part of the join-condition ( `CL."table" = 'V'` ) to the `WHERE` clause.

b) Removing the JOIN completely and rewrite it to

```
IF (( SELECT COUNT(1) FROM CL WHERE "table" = 'V' ) > 0 )
BEGIN
  <Do something which references the bottleneck-View V>
END
```

If the IF-Condition returns false, I hoped that the Code between BEGIN AND END is not executed. But it is. Runtime of the Query in b) is nearly the same as a `SELECT * FROM V`, even if there's no record with `table ='V'` in CL).

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Could you add the real code.

Comment: @valex No, I'm sorry, but the code is too complex and includes references to Microsoft Axapta-tables. But I added information and tried to explain the problem more detailled.

Comment: @valex If you want to test it on your won, you just need a view which takes a few seconds to do a select on it and put an `if ( 1 =2 ) begin ... end` around it!

Comment: Try it with a if exists(select) instead of if (0 < select count), btw try that select count to check if it's returning the right results

Comment: @jean Tried your suggestion - it's exactly the same behaviour. The runtime for the code `if exists(select 1 from CL where "table" = 'xy') begin select * from V end` is the same runtime which is needed for executing just the `select * from V`, even if the `if exists...` query returns false...